# Shapefile zipcode area merge

Tags: shapefile

I have a shapefile containing the ZipCode areas.

For performance reasons, I want to create a new shapefile that contains sales territories, which are a collection of ZipCodes.

So instead of use a shapefile with 40K+ shapes, I want to generate one that has the couple of hundred sales territories, where the shape of the territory is the merged shape of all ZipCodes in that territory.

What tools are available to do this??

Answer (score 0):

You need a planar geometry library.  Here are a few:

- [JTS Topology Suite](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html) - a Java library
- [GEOS](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/) - a C++ version of JTS
- [Shapely](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely) - a Python wrapper for GEOS